# Python: one variable but different values?

Tags: python, variables

I have a line of code from Python forbidden fruit module:

```
__all__ = 'curse', 'curses', 'reverse'
```

I know what strings are and I know what arrays and tuples are. What kind of variable is this? How can we use this and for what?

Comment: It's a tuple. Tuples are defined by commas, not parentheses.

Comment: possible dup : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: @IMCoins: No, that's about the special variable `__all__`, and says nothing about the syntax used here.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: while Python does have arrays, they are rarely used compared to the far more common built-in data type, `list`. If you're reading a tutorial that calls `[1,2,3]` an array, find a new tutorial.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand, but he could have selected ANY variable, and he chose this specific one. That sounds more than a coincidence to me. Like : He wanted to know what `__all__` was, since he already said "I know what a tuple is". :) his question might be poorly formulated, but I believe I got it right -- EDIT : Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @IMCoins: the question is indeed very unclear in that respect. I was going by the question title: *one variable but different values?*.

Comment: hi - op here, my question was based on syntax. I didn't know a tuple could be created without the parenthesis. I only used the __all__ variable because thats how I found it in the module and I thought it may have been important. I learned what its for from that link too though. thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a tuple. If you want to find out the type of something, use the `type` function - e.g.

```
type(__all__)
```